# How to assign orginal id for two columns value relationship in Snowflake/SQL

Tags: sql

I have data below. Here there are two set of records. First set 111 to 444 and second set 1111 to 2222.

| CLAIM_ID | ADJ_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | NULL |
| 111 | NULL |
| 222 | 111 |
| 222 | 111 |
| 333 | 222 |
| 333 | 222 |
| 444 | 333 |
| 444 | 333 |
| 1111 | NULL |
| 1111 | NULL |
| 2222 | 1111 |
| 2222 | 1111 |

My expected output is need to assign orginal id for first set and second set.

How to achieve this in Snowflake.

| ORG_ID | CLAIM_ID | ADJ_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 111 | NULL |
| 111 | 111 | NULL |
| 111 | 222 | 111 |
| 111 | 222 | 111 |
| 111 | 333 | 222 |
| 111 | 333 | 222 |
| 111 | 444 | 333 |
| 111 | 444 | 333 |
| 1111 | 1111 | NULL |
| 1111 | 1111 | NULL |
| 1111 | 2222 | 1111 |
| 1111 | 2222 | 1111 |

Comment: I think you're looking at a recursive query. Is there a limit to the number of links in the chain? (And I doubt anybody will answer until you specify which db platform you're on.) This looks like the typical hierarchical org chart query. You just need to follow it up to the top until you find a null.

Comment: If you add a tag for your specific DBMS, such as [sql-server], [oracle], [mysql], etc., you will reach a larger audience including those who specialize in the specific DBMS you are working on.

Comment: What is the significance of the duplicate rows? For a given CLAIM_ID, would there aver be multiple distinct ADJ_ID values? Can you guarantee that there will never be any reference loops such as 444 -> 333 -> 222 -> 444?

Comment: What happens if a row has multiple parents? e.g. 3333 -> 444 and also 3333 -> 2222

Comment: This is trying in Snowflake. Multiple parents will not be there in data. e.g. 3333 -> 444 and also 3333 -> 2222

Answer (score 0):

*(I am not a Snowflake developer, so I have developed this answer using SQL Server. It appears that the Snowflake syntax is similar.)*

You can use a recursive *common table expression* (CTE) to build the hierarchy. The CTE would first select the top level ORG_IDs and then recursively expand the hierarchy to the lower levels. The results can then be joined back with the original data.

Note: Because SQL Server CTEs do not permit the use of DISTINCT, GROUP BY, or window functions to de-dup the data, this is done in a separate step ahead of time. I do not know whether or not Snowflake has the same restrictions.

Something similar to the following should work.

```
WITH CTE_DistinctData AS (
    -- Recursive CTEs can't use DISTINCT, so we need to
    -- eliminate the duplicates in advance
    SELECT DISTINCT D.CLAIM_ID, D.ADJ_ID
    FROM Data D
),
RECURSIVE CTE_Hierarchy AS (  -- I believe Snowflake requires the RECURSIVE keyword
    -- Top level where ADJ_ID is null
    SELECT DD.CLAIM_ID, DD.CLAIM_ID AS ORG_ID
    FROM CTE_DistinctData DD
    WHERE ADJ_ID IS NULL
    -- Recursively expand to lower levels
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DD.CLAIM_ID, H.ORG_ID  
    FROM CTE_Hierarchy H
    JOIN CTE_DistinctData DD ON DD.ADJ_ID = H.CLAIM_ID
)
SELECT H.ORG_ID, D.CLAIM_ID, D.ADJ_ID
FROM Data D
JOIN CTE_Hierarchy H
    ON H.CLAIM_ID = D.CLAIM_ID
ORDER BY H.CLAIM_ID;
```

Results:

| ORG_ID | CLAIM_ID | ADJ_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 111 | *null* |
| 111 | 111 | *null* |
| 111 | 222 | 111 |
| 111 | 222 | 111 |
| 111 | 333 | 222 |
| 111 | 333 | 222 |
| 111 | 444 | 333 |
| 111 | 444 | 333 |
| 1111 | 1111 | *null* |
| 1111 | 1111 | *null* |
| 1111 | 2222 | 1111 |
| 1111 | 2222 | 1111 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5pH4L3Df) for a Demo. This demo runs on SQL Server. I could not find an equivalent fiddle site for snowflake.

See the Snowflake [Working with CTEs (Common Table Expressions)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte) documentation page and search for "WITH RECURSIVE managers" for a similar example.

*If someone knows of a snowflake fiddle site or otherwise identifies errors in the above, please add a comment below or better yet, update this answer.*

Comment: Above solutions working fine. thank you so much for your response !